# How to correctly handle html tags in textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net, escaping, textarea, xss

I have an asp.net form with a textarea element (part of member profile - Objectives field). I don't mind users entering html tags in there, but asp.net doesn't allow submitting html tags inside text boxes for security reasons (), which is good. So, I see two options - strip html tags completely from textarea's value before form submission, or escape textarea's value, replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` before submitting to the server.

In other words, if someone typed following in the textarea:

[image]

I want to somehow save it on the server and show it to the user exactly as they typed it  next time they are on that page.

How is such a problem usually handled?

UPDATE: Asp.net doesn't allow you to submit tags in the input/textarea elements by default. And if I disable that check, I open a potential for XSS exploits. All I want is to find a correct way to escape input (and assign back to the element) and then be able to unescape it after the form loads

Comment: Is this webforms or MVC?

Comment: It depends on if you want HTML in your content. If so, escape them going in and unescape it coming out. If you don't want HTML, then just strip them out before submitting to the DB.

Comment: Do not escape on input, but on output. You can safely send your text to the server (properly encoded, but that should be done automatically when using ‘standard’ form POSTs) and save the user's input in a database (of course, beware of SQL injections). Properly transform problematic characters to HTML entities when outputting your text, at least `<`, `>` and `&` (and perhaps others as well). I can't provide you an answer, as I'm not at all accustomed to ASP.net. BTW, *never* strip out tags, because you might as well maim something like `a<c^2&b>3`.

Comment: @Marcel: What's the danger of `a<c^2&b>3`?

Comment: If you bluntly strip everything between `<…>`, you'll change that string to `a3`.

Comment: @Marcel: and? what's the danger of a3? Am I missing something?

Comment: Let's give a better example: if someone want to talk about `<script>` elements, as I just did, I don't want the program to remove that word, it should just properly encode/translate the angle brackets.

Comment: I'm wondering why my question has been down voted...

Comment: @Marcel: Ok, Got you! I thought you meant to say that stripping tags might be some sort of security problem, that's why I was curious

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is both client-side and server-side validation:

- [Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library for ASP.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx)
- [Making HTML safer: details for toStaticHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh465388.aspx)
- [Differences Between AntiXss.HtmlEncode and HttpUtility.HtmlEncode Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/07/09/differences-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode-methods.aspx)
- [JavaScript Attack/Defend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh243615.aspx)
- [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)